# How to continue using gdb to debug c++ code after reconnecting to remote Ubuntu machine using ssh?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ubuntu, gdb

My local machine is of Windows 10 and I have a bad network condition.

So when I ssh to log in remote Ubuntu machine, and try to debug using gdb, which costs perhaps 30 minutes to the breakpoint, I often get `connection close` error.

And when I ssh again, I have to start over.

Is there a recoverable function of gdb so that I can continue using it after reconnecting?

Comment: Can't you run/debug locally? Or fix your bad network situation?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Nope, the procedure needs 50GB memory which's beyond my local machine's capacity. I'm trying to fix the network, but, well, it's hard to say whether it can be fixed.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest / cheapest solution is to just buy more RAM 

Comment: @JesperJuhl A good option if I have a desktop.

Comment: You can buy laptop RAM as well no?

Comment: Could it be there's no I/O for some interval -- leading to one side dropping the connection?  Try adding the line `ServerAliveInterval 60` to your `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: There are programs designed to handle reconnecting to disconnected shell sessions - `tmux` and `screen`.

Comment: @BaileyKocin No, the socket number is limited.

Comment: @Milag there is no `~/.ssh/config` for me, so `ServerAliveInterval ` is `0`. Perhaps your solution will work, I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick My local machine is of Windows 10. And both `tmux` and `screen` are Unix software, so, unfortunately...

Comment: Its OK to have a Windows system locally. You would run tmux or screen just after logging in to the remote  Ubuntu system. They might already be installed by default on the Ubuntu system.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick After an investigation, yep you're right. Thanks! I think it's been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a recoverable function of gdb so that I can continue using it after reconnecting?

No.

You need to use a program designed to keep your session alive: [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). Spending time learning to use them well now will pay for itself many times over.

Comment: My local machine is of Windows 10. Sorry I didn't mention it previously.

Comment: @BingZhao https://superuser.com/a/313606/112397 -- you can install CygWin and use `screen` from a Windows machine.